# A storybook error related to 'emotion' occurred in an environment using swc

Tags: storybook, emotion, swc

I am using the existing babel and switching to swc.

But the following error occurred.

```
Error: Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin, the swc Emotion plugin, or another Emotion-aware compiler transform.
```

My next.config.js settings are as follows

```
{
  ...
  swcMinify: true,
  compiler: {
    emotion: true,
  }
};
```

In the existing Babel environment, "@emotion/babel-plugin" was imported and used.

Also, no errors occurred in Storybook.

Is there anything I need to do additionally to use storybook in swc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storybook version 7 or above, please refer to the following instructions.

Starting from Storybook version 7, it no longer supports Babel configuration out of the box, so you will need a separate Babel configuration (babelrc) in your project (ref: https://storybook.js.org/docs/html/configure/babel). By setting up the babelrc as follows, the `@emotion/babel-plugin` will work correctly in Storybook:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["@emotion"]
}
```

To prevent babelrc from affecting the next build, you can configure next.config.js as follows:

```
  experimental: {
    forceSwcTransforms: true,
  }
```

By adding the experimental object with the forceSwcTransforms set to true, you ensure that the Babel configuration will not interfere with the next build process